# mysql having statement returning no rows

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to assign the right `fifo_cost` to a given order based on the difference between `fifo_in_date` and `order_date`: the `fifo_cost` associated to the smallest difference between `order_date` and `fifo_date_in` should be assigned to that order.

The following mysql snippet won't return any record. I'd expect it to return that one record with the `fifo_date_in` closest to the `order_date`, but clearly I'm missing something.

```
drop table if exists tmp;

create table tmp (
order_sequence int,
order_number int,
order_date date,
fifo_date_in date,
fifo_cost float);

INSERT INTO tmp (order_sequence, order_number, order_date, fifo_date_in, fifo_cost) VALUES (5613, 561, '2013-01-02','2009-01-01',1.55);
INSERT INTO tmp (order_sequence, order_number, order_date, fifo_date_in, fifo_cost) VALUES (5613, 561, '2013-01-02','2009-02-01',2.55);
INSERT INTO tmp (order_sequence, order_number, order_date, fifo_date_in, fifo_cost) VALUES (5613, 561, '2013-01-02','2009-03-01',3.55);
INSERT INTO tmp (order_sequence, order_number, order_date, fifo_date_in, fifo_cost) VALUES (5613, 561, '2013-01-02','2009-04-01',4.55);
INSERT INTO tmp (order_sequence, order_number, order_date, fifo_date_in, fifo_cost) VALUES (5613, 561, '2013-01-02','2009-05-01',5.55);

SELECT
  order_sequence, order_number, order_date, fifo_date_in, fifo_cost, datediff(order_date,fifo_date_in) as ddiff
FROM tmp
GROUP BY order_sequence, order_number, order_date
HAVING datediff(order_date,fifo_date_in) = min(datediff(order_date,fifo_date_in))
```

Comment: First of all I think you need to include fifo_date_in and fifo_cost into your group by clause as these are regular columns without any aggregate functions. Secondly if you run the query without the having clause at the end does that yield any results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to get the cost, I think you have to find the min and join back to the base table:

```
SELECT t.order_sequence, t.order_number, t.order_date, t.fifo_date_in, t.fifo_cost
  FROM tmp t
  INNER JOIN ( SELECT order_sequence, order_number, order_date
                     ,MIN(datediff(order_date,fifo_date_in)) as ddiff
                 FROM tmp
                 GROUP BY order_sequence, order_number, order_date
              ) m
         ON (m.order_sequence = t.order_sequence
             AND m.order_number = t.order_number
             AND m.order_date = t.order_date
             AND datediff(t.order_date, t.fifo_date_in) = m.ddiff)
```

Also, you may have to consider absolute value if closest can mean before or after.

Here's the [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8ccd0/2)

Comment: Thanks (particularly for the SQLFIDDLE link, very useful). The "min & join back" solution in mysql seems popular for this problem. Is it possible to get the same result without the subquery, using HAVING?

Comment: Actually, you'll have to thank @ChristianMark for the fiddle (thanks, Christian!). I don't know how to do it without some kind of subquery. The `group by` identifies the key. Then there are two items associated with the key: `fifo_date_in` and `fifo_cost`. An aggregate function would need to be applied to each of these. But what aggregate to apply to `fifo_cost`? We don't know until we determine the min on date, hence the need for a join or subquery. I can't think of another way offhand.

Comment: Np. Glad to help. Thanks to your answer though I just apply it to the Scheme.=D @user2105469, I think it cant be done without the subquery, create a `VIEW` instead.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your query is the having statement.

What you want to do is a `MIN(datediff(order_date,fifo_date_in)) as ddiff` in the select which will find the lowest value of the difference. You then use your `group by` to group the results. Scratch my comment from before, your `group by` is actually correct:

```
drop table if exists tmp;

create table tmp (
order_sequence int,
order_number int,
order_date date,
fifo_date_in date,
fifo_cost float);

INSERT INTO tmp (order_sequence, order_number, order_date, fifo_date_in, fifo_cost) VALUES (5613, 561, '2013-01-02','2009-01-01',1.55);
INSERT INTO tmp (order_sequence, order_number, order_date, fifo_date_in, fifo_cost) VALUES (5613, 561, '2013-01-02','2009-02-01',2.55);
INSERT INTO tmp (order_sequence, order_number, order_date, fifo_date_in, fifo_cost) VALUES (5613, 561, '2013-01-02','2009-03-01',3.55);
INSERT INTO tmp (order_sequence, order_number, order_date, fifo_date_in, fifo_cost) VALUES (5613, 561, '2013-01-02','2009-04-01',4.55);
INSERT INTO tmp (order_sequence, order_number, order_date, fifo_date_in, fifo_cost) VALUES (5613, 561, '2013-01-02','2009-05-01',5.55);


SELECT
  order_sequence, order_number, order_date, fifo_date_in, fifo_cost, MIN(datediff(order_date,fifo_date_in)) as ddiff
FROM tmp
GROUP BY order_sequence, order_number, order_date
```

Comment: Doesn't this pick the minimum of `datediff` regardless of cost?

Comment: yes this returns the lowest ddiff item, it does not take into account any cost, do you need the lowest cost as well?

Comment: I'm trying to fetch the cost associated to the most recent fifo_date_in, i.e. the latest cost on file. The fifo_date_in value itself isn't that important, it being the most recent is.

Comment: well the query returns the cost associated with the lowest ddif, I am not sure I understand your question :)

Comment: The lowest ddif occurs for fifo_date_in = '2009-05-01' (last record in the table), and the cost associated with that fifo date is 5.55. In the query above, the right ddif is returned, but with the first record in the table, not the last one (which contains the cost associated with the min ddif).

Answer (score 0):

You can use ORDER BY and LIMIT, and omit the GROUP BY:

```
SELECT
  order_sequence, order_number, order_date, fifo_date_in, fifo_cost, datediff(order_date,fifo_date_in) as ddiff
FROM tmp 
ORDER BY ddiff
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Doesn't this return a single record, regardless of the number of unique order_numbers?

Comment: @user2105469 yes, the sample data only had 1 order number. I'll add another query for all order numbers